# Data lineage in SQL Server Denali

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I see a lot of mentioning of the new feature "Data lineage and Impact Analysis" in SQL Server codename Denali, nevertheless all my attempts to make this feature work seem to result in failures. Did anyone managed to make it work or came across a blog that has a step by step approach?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the [MSDN docs on Determining Impact and Data Lineage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff877969(v=SQL.110).aspx) in SQL Server Denali.

Well, that link is dead and I can’t quickly find an update. [This blog post](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2016/05/12/sql-server-data-lineage-tracking-etl-processes-notes-field-124/) might be helpful.

Comment: The link is dead